# Reading a file in every time vs saving to core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a word game where my app is required to load a text file that has over 225,000 words (2.6 MB) before the app begins. So in other words, this process is done every time the user starts the app. My question is would it be better to load the word list once (the very first time the user plays) and then save it to core data for use every time after that? Would there be a significantly increase in performance in loading the list vs reading the list in?

It seems to me that this is a no brainer and that saving to core data would definitely be the best way to go.

I am just curious to see on what everybody else thinks about the comparison between these two options.

Comment: Is the file stored locally or remotely?

Comment: The file is stored locally on the device.

Comment: Then duplicating it to CoreData will roughly double the storage space your app requires for the words, so that's a consideration that cannot be ignored... but with that said... you can distribute your app with a preloaded Core Data database instead of a text file...

Comment: That is an interesting thought but since it is just roughly under 3MB, I don't feel like a duplicate copy of it would be a huge issue. I am more interested in the performance aspect of it. In other words, I wan't the way that is going to load the app the fastest for my users.

Comment: Then distribute the Core Data database with your app, which does both things best.

Answer (score 0):

Your "no-brainer" answer is indeed correct. I cannot imagine a scenario where you would keep these in memory for any meaningful reason.

I would recommend to include a pre-populated Core Data store in your app bundle and copying this file to the application sandbox upon first start. You can still have text import functionality during your development.

With a NSFetchedResultsController you can, say, generate a truly random word from your list in a very simple and efficient way. Both memory and performance will be no issue whatsoever.

Answer (score -2):

If the memory use is a concern then you could use `mmap(2)` to enable the operating system to decide whether to keep the word list in memory.  Memory mapping the file allows the kernel to throw away individual pages of memory and then reload them later if the system is under memory pressure, but will keep the entire file in memory if there is plenty available.

In contrast, if you read the file into memory, then when the system comes under memory pressure it will have to *write* the pages to swap, which is more costly.